# « Et tu vas l'être encore plus ! »

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

À la fin du 25e épisode de la saison 2 (Le marriage au Canterlot) du dessin animé *My Little Pony : Les Amies, C'est Magique !*, [l'échange final](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJE2SXNNRAg) est le suivant :

> « Je suis désolée ... » dit Twilight Sparkle, en pleurant.
>
> « Et tu vas l'être encore plus ! » dit la reine Chrysalis (déguisée en princesse Cadence)

Et Chrysalis lance un sortilège pour envoyer Twilight dans une grotte qui est sous terre.

**Ma question est :**

Pourquoi utilise-t-on « encore plus » au lieu de « même plus » ? Quand utilise-t-on « encore » et quand utilise-t-on « même » ? Les deux mots semblent équivalents à l'adverbe « even » en anglais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La phrase :

> Et tu vas l'être même plus !

n'est pas idiomatique car, alors que dans « encore plus » **plus** est toujours pris dans le sens de *more*, dans « même plus » il a le plus souvent le sens opposé de *(not) anymore*.

> Elle est encore plus désolée : *She is even more sorry.*
>
> Elle [n']est même plus désolée : *She is not even sorry anymore.*

Pour que **même plus** ait clairement un sens positif, il faudrait que désolée ait un complément:

> Elle est même plus désolée que moi : *She is even more sorry than I (am).*

Answer (score 3):

Je pense qu'on utilisera plutôt « même » lorsqu'on suggérera quelque chose de différent, tandis qu'on utilisera "encore" pour affirmer davantage un résultat.

Exemple :

> Je serai grand ?
> — Tu seras même bleu !
>
> Je serai grande comme ça ?
> — Tu seras encore plus grande que ça !

Cependant « même » et « encore » ont un sens très proche.

Il n'est donc pas faux de dire :

> Je serai grande ?
> — Tu seras même très grande !

Couramment on utilise « même » lorsqu'on souhaite affirmer la probabilité d'une hypothèse (« même si … », « même en supposant que … »).